# Django: how to join and annotate multiple sql tables?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm building a sample django app and I can't aggregate properly some sql results.

Consider these 3 models:

**Movie model**

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    source_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators=[MinLengthValidator(1)])
```

**Rating model**

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[MinLengthValidator(1)])
```

**Comment model**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[MinLengthValidator(1)])
    body = models.TextField()
```

Then consider the following mysql tables:

**movie**

```
+-----------+-----------+
| source_id |   title   |
+-----------+-----------+
| 15sdfsd4  | Spiderman |
+-----------+-----------+
```

**rating**

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| id | rating | username | movie_id |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
|  1 |      4 | jack     | 15sdfsd4 |
|  2 |      3 | mick     | 15sdfsd4 |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
```

**comment**

```
+----+----------+--------------------+----------+
| id | username |        body        | movie_id |
+----+----------+--------------------+----------+
|  1 | charles  | I loved this movie | 15sdfsd4 |
|  2 | mick     | Nice sound fx      | 15sdfsd4 |
+----+----------+--------------------+----------+
```

I would like to query for a list of movie ids and get a summary of the avg rating and the nr of comments.

I tried something like

```
ids = ['15sdfsd4','54fdf5d']
m = Movie.objects.filter(source_id__in=ids).annotate(Avg('rating'), Count('comment'))
```

I would expect a comment count of 2 and an avg rating of 3.5 for the movie with id *15sdfsd4*. Instead I get a comment count of 4 and an avg rating of 1.5 which I can't make much sense of...

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Hi Crash, Please try it: Movie.objects.annotate(avg_rating = Avg('rating_set__all'), com_count = Count('comment_set_all'))       or        Movie.objects.all().annotate(avg_rating = Avg('rating_set__all'), com_count = Count('comment_set_all'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two thing that are wrong with following solution

- You are not specifying column to average on ( rating_rating )
- Django combining multiple annotations [bug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) and [thread](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060#comment:60)

Considering count aggregate has distinct and average with duplicates is same this would probably work

```
 m = Movie.objects.filter(source_id__in=ids).annotate(
     Avg('rating__rating'), 
     Count('comment',distinct=True)
 )
```

Comment: Hi @iklinac, by using `Avg('rating_rating')` I get `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'rating_rating' into field. Choices are: comment, rating, source_id, title`, the error disappears when using just `Avg('rating')`. Anyway, only the `Count()` gives the correct result `2` while the `Avg()` gives `2.0000`. Is it due to the bug you pointed out in the answer?

Comment: @crash double underscore rating__rating, and yes look at the documentation links provided.

Comment: Thanks again @iklinac it works with the double underscore, could you tell me what it was doing with `Avg('rating')` vs `Avg('rating__rating')` ?

Comment: @crash with rating it was averaging id

Comment: try distinct on Avg also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146267/discussion-between-iklinac-and-crash).